# dual boot windows/ubuntu only loads windows loader, will not load grub, will not boot ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, grub, bcdedit

I have a successful dual boot installation of ubuntu 20 with windows 11.  However, upon reset, the system always goes to the windows loader rather than to grub, so I cannot boot ubuntu.

However, in windows I can go to System recovery -> advanced startup -> troubleshoot -> advanced options -> UEFI firmware settings -> F9 Boot Menu and at this point it shows me 2 boot loaders: one for windows (at top) and one for ubuntu (2nd).  I can select one or the other, but cannot change the order.  If I select the ubuntu loader, it starts grub, shows me an option for windows as well as ubuntu, and will boot ubuntu if selected.

The names of these "loaders" are:  "OS Boot Manager (UEFI) - Windows Boot Manager (WDC...)" and "OS Boot Manager (UEFI) - ubuntu (WDC...)"

Obviously this procedure is not practical and I would like the machine to boot into grub rather than the windows loader.

I believe that bcdedit should be able to set this up.  Here it identifies the 2 boot loaders (one is a "boot manager" in its description, and the other a "boot loader"):

C:\windows\system32>bcdedit /v

### Windows Boot Manager

identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\ubuntu\grubx.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
default                 {1edd7570-7b59-11ec-b259-c018033ee9ae}
resumeobject            {1edd756f-7b59-11ec-b259-c018033ee9ae}
displayorder            {1edd7570-7b59-11ec-b259-c018033ee9ae}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 30

### Windows Boot Loader

identifier              {1edd7570-7b59-11ec-b259-c018033ee9ae}

device                  partition=C:
path                    \windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {fecd3499-7b61-11ec-88f8-c018033ee9ae}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \windows
resumeobject            {1edd756f-7b59-11ec-b259-c018033ee9ae}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
I have tried the following commands, one at a time, and rebooted each time, still with the same result, i.e. it just boots to windows:

C:\windows\system32>bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx.efi The operation completed successfully.

C:\windows\system32>bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx.efi The operation completed successfully.

C:\windows\system32>bcdedit /default {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795} The operation completed successfully.

Hoping that someone with more knowledge of bcdedit and the windows/boot interactions can suggest how to approach this.  Thanks.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68581/how-can-i-prevent-windows-from-overwriting-grub-when-using-a-dual-boot-machine . Also, I've 1. renamed the windows...efi to old_windows.efi, 2. renamed the grub...efi to windows...efi (where ... are minor name differences) and the PC's consistently boot to grub2, even after a Windows update.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Windows, its bootloader or Ubuntu and its bootloader. Ideally you want to boot from Ubuntu (Grub) so you have both OSes as options in the Grub menu (Windows can't boot other OSes unless they are other Windows). In order to do that most firmwares allow users to select it at the Boot menu. But some laptops, some HP models and others, keep overriding that user selection and booting Windows directly. So, the best option (HP) is immediately after powering on to press ESC and then F9 to explicitly select Ubuntu.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Some answers in that link aren't applicable (BIOS/MBR) and others are no longer recommended because you can't simply change the Windows bootloader to point to Grub with impunity.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, though I can't vouch for the links, I *have* changed the bootloader and it *worked*. Willi ti work in *every* situation, I don't know.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik What is currently recommended is what I mentioned ESC > F9 > Select Ubuntu for HPs and a similar sequence to the other very few that do the same. Or choose hardware that is dual-boot "friendly" from the start. Or simply delete Windows.